# Why do we put the in this example?

Tags: definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Nearly $300 billion in foreign aid was spent by the U.S. Government between **the years** 2013 and 2018 (source: Forbes)

I seriously don't know why we put "the years" in the sentence. More formal? For me, I won't put "the years" in the sentence at all.

Comment: This is a matter of style. Thus it’s off-topic, and given that it’s a style question, cannot be judged without more context.  Just because a phrase can be left out doesn’t mean it should be.

Comment: It's to be very clear (a) that years are involved, not some other number; (b) precisely when the beginning and ending points were. It's just good journalism, with all the bells and whistles left in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when *year* is followed by a number without an article, it refers to an ordinal year or set of years in a short sequence, for example,
*We finally reached our financial goal in year five of our project.*
or
*The child learns this skill in years 2 and 3.*

You are right that in your example, you can omit *years* entirely, and say *between 2013 and 2018*, but if you include *years*, you should include the article *the*. That will distinguish it from the use above (*year 2*).